# How to setup feedback link on Windows Forms caption using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to setup Feedback link on every windows form, so that user can send suggestion about design, functionality etc.. using C# (.NET 3.5) but I could not find solution.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **every** form?  You could create a "FeedbackLink" UserControl, and place that whereever you like.  I wouldn't recommend trying to do it as a clever blanket-thing, because you can never assume the place you want the feedback hyperlink won't be used by something else.

My suggestion would actually be to add it to the "Help" menu on your main form, and possibly in some kind of (very intrusive) pop-up dialog.  Maybe do it the way Visual Studio tackles it - by putting an icon in the systray with a bubble that pops up for the user to click on?

Example image (might take a second or two to appear):
[Example http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b7939d58ae.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b7939d58ae.png)